# CustomLayout for Bottom Tabbed Activity

Tags: android, layout, fragment, android-tablayout

I have a tabbedactivity layout, but i need to customize that layout for swipe between 2 activities, like this.

[image]

I cant change the background color, just the line indicator. Anyone knows how can i do that?

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbarBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabsBottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

thx!

Comment: Did you check my answer?did it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color of an item selected you'll have to use **app:tabBackground**
and set custom selector.

tab_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</selector>
```

TabLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector">...
```

Comment: I have  other problem. Now the AppBarLayout is on the TabLayout, and i have different colors for both. Its not possible to change a first half to medium red and other half to dark red (OF APPBARLAYOUT).